# How can I lazy load my UIViews inside a vertical UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

I've got a vertical UIScrollView which contains several thumbnails (UIViews). Within my viewWillAppear I'm filling my UIScrollView with 200 thumbnails.

Scrolling and representing this view doesn't take long however loading my entire thumbnailview does. So I'm looking for a way where I can display the first 20 thumbnails on viewWillAppear and load the rest on the delegate method of the UIScrollView `-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{`.

However an actual implementation is not really clear to me. Do I preload all the thumbnails on viewWillAppear or only the first 20? How can I trace the location for the new thumbnails which needs to be drawn on scrollViewDidScroll? Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's the implementation of my current viewWillAppear which draws my thumbnails

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
            birdRow = (int) floor(i / 4);
            birdColumn = (i % 4) + 1; 
            paddingX = 125;
            UIView * thumbnail = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170*birdColumn - paddingX, 180*birdRow + 20, 160, 170)];
            [scroller addSubview:thumbnail];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What i have done is some what different from what you want or same with some modification if i get you right just see the below code

for storing the last position of scroll view

```
float lastContentOffset;
```

Also uses one for tracking the index of data to load afterwords required data

```
NSInteger index;
```

At the time of first time feeling the scrollView i assign the value to index and lastContentOffset

```
index = Currently shown image index;
lastContentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset.x;//it shows currently visible rect's origin's x value
```

Now in the Scroll View's Delegate Method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` I use to change values like below

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"ScrollViewDidScroll is called"); 
    if(lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        index += (int)(scrollview.contentOffset.x - lastContentOffset)/scrollview.frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"Index incremented %d",index);
        //Load required new images also can remove some of the images
    }
    else if(lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        index -= (int)(lastContentOffset - scrollview.contentOffset.x)/scrollview.frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"Index decremented %d",index);
        //Load required new images also can remove some of the images
    }
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    NSLog(@"New lastContentOffset %.2f",lastContentOffset);
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose to put this in this delegate method. This is only launched when the UIScrollViews stops scrolling by itself and the scrollViewDidScroll is called on all scrollevents. What type of meganism did you used for drawing the views?

Answer (score 1):

Use a UICollectionView. It will lazy-load the UICollectionViewCells just like a UITableView will lazy-load the rows.

Each cell can be a thumbnail or whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Make Operation Queue (NSOperation Queue) for the views.

below link will help you out:
http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/